# Find an example of $X, Y, \mathcal{A}$, and $f$ to show that $f$ is not necessarily continuous

Tags: general-topology

I have this exercise where it says that we let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of closed subsets of X such that $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A=X$. Assume that for every $A\in \mathcal{A}$ the restriction $f\restriction_{A}:A \to Y$ of $f$ to $A$ is continuous.

I have to find an example of $X, Y$, $\mathcal{A}$, and $f$ to show that $f$ is not necessarily continuous when $\mathcal{A}$ does not satisfy the condition that for each $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that the intersection $A\cap U$ is non-empty for only finitely many $A\in \mathcal{A}$.

I am a little confused about for which example this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the rationals $\Bbb Q$ can be seen as the countable union of its singletons (a very non-locally finite union of closed sets). $f\restriction_{\{q\}}$ is trivially continuous for *any* $f$...

Comment: So for this it is that we let $X=Y=\mathbb{Q}$?, and we let $\mathcal{A}$ be that set of rational singletons? How do I then show that f is not continuous?

Comment: @Sara can you find a non-continuous $f$ ? any one will do. $Y$ can be anything you like.

Comment: So I can for example look at the function $tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$? Then I'll have left to show that there does not exist a neighborhood U for each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that the intersection $\{a\}\cap U$ is non-empty  for only finitely many   $\{a\}\in\mathcal{A}$ where $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. But how can I do that?

Comment: @Sara pick a different function, yours is continuous on its domain and non-defined for $x=0$. Every open set in $\Bbb Q$ is infinite, so that last fact is obvious.

Comment: can I then say $f(x)=tan(x)$? or is it continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Sara that’s continuous on $\Bbb Q$ of course. There are plenty of non continuous functions.

Comment: I am sure there are, but I can just not think of any..

Comment: @Sara there *are* such things are search engines?

Answer (score 0):

Take any Hausdorff topological space $X$. The each set $\{x\}$ is closed and, for *any* function $f$, $f|_{\{x\}}$ is continuous.